# JSONAPI Resource: has_one/many with polymorphic associations

Tags: jsonapi-resources

I have a model `Order` that has addresses like this:

```
 has_many :pick_up_addresses,
       -> { where(address_type: Address.address_types[:pick_up]) },
       as: :addressable, class_name: 'Address', dependent: :destroy


has_one :destination_address,
      -> { where(address_type: Address.address_types[:destination]) },
      as: :addressable, class_name: 'Address', dependent: :destroy
```

An example of fields in the `Address` model is:

```
addressable_id: 1
addressable_type: "Order"
```

I defined an `AddressResource`, but I don't know what my `OrderResource` should look like. In this case:

```
# OrderResource
has_many :pick_up_addresses
has_one :destination_address
```

does not work.

If I add `?include=destination_address` to the URL for Order, I get:

```
undefined method `destination_address_id' for class `#<Class:0x007fe321b8cae8>'
```

And for `?include=pick_up_addresses` I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `object' for #<Api::V2::AddressResource:0x007fe32abc90c0>\nDid you mean?  object_id
```

I've looked at the documentation for defining relations (http://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.9/guide/resources.html#Relationships), but I'm not sure any of these options defines what I need here.

PS - Attempting to add `polymorphic: true` still yields the following errors:

```
undefined method `type' for #<Address:0x007fe32f08d1c0> # for pick_up_address

undefined method `destination_address_id' for class `#<Class:0x007fe322db5f58>'" # for destination_address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. For anyone else needing help:

In `OrderResource`:

```
has_many :pick_up_addresses, polymorphic: true
has_one :destination_address, polymorphic: true, foreign_key: 'addressable_id'
```

And in the `Address` model:

```
def type
  'address'
end
```